# Emacs is compiled with imagemagick and has right PATH but still cannot use it

Tags: org-mode, osx, images

I want to use emacs with imagemagick to enable dynamic resizing of images in org-mode (https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/44id5o/how_to_install_emacs_with_imagemagick_support/). This used to work before I decided to upgrade homebrew.

I have installed imagemagick with homebrew, and it seems to work because I have a working `convert` command:

`$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.4-5 Q16 x86_64 2017-01-23 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype jng jpeg ltdl lzma png rsvg tiff x xml zlib`

I then installed emacs with homebrew on mac, using the following command:

`brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick`

The installation completes without issues. Starting emacs works fine, and I use exec-path-from-shell in my .emacs to get the right PATH:

`(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t
  :if (eq system-type 'darwin)
  :config (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)`

This seems to work, since the command

`M-: (getenv "PATH")`

returns

`"/Users/my_user_name/Library/Python/2.7/bin:/Users/my_user_name/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin"`

However, the images in my org mode file do not resize properly (which they used to before I decided to upgrade homebrew, forcing me to reinstall emacs). Checking if imagemagick works by running the following command just returns `nil`:

`M-: (image-type-available-p 'imagemagick) RET`

What am I missing?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Standard emacs and imagemagick from macports works fine for me. Emacs needs the path to the imagemagick library not the binary files like convert.

Answer (score 2):

The best "solution" I was able to find was to use the "emacs-mac" port of emacs (https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport):

```
brew tap railwaycat/emacsmacport

brew cask install emacs-mac
```

Although the emacs-mac port works very well (perhaps better than the nextstep port you get through brew install emacs), this is not a perfect answer because it would be nice to be able to compile standard emacs too.